# Add parameters to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have an API to a list of images. The API has 5 parameters listed below:

- first the keyword for what to search (eg: flowers)
- second parameter size (has a default value),
- third orientation (no default value),
- forth author (no default value),
- fifth date (no default value)

How do I add parameters in ReactJS that has no default values to the URL?
For the other 2,

I used the state.

```
state={
   key:"",
   size:"2mb",
}
```

My uURL is `https://xxxxxx.com/api/&value={this.state.key}&size={this.state.size}`

I want to select parameters with no default value the url becomes :
`https://xxxxxx.com/api/&value={this.state.key}&size={this.state.size}&orientation=landscape&date=10.10.2010`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL as a string, manipulate, and modify it using `window.location.href`